# CSS styling not applying to Dockerized Django project

Tags: python, django, docker

I created a django project, life was good. However when I dockerized it everything else works fine apart from the css styling. Below is my dockerfile, let me know any other information I can provide

```
FROM python:3.8

WORKDIR /app

COPY . /app

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 8000

ENV NAME World

RUN python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

I feel like ive tried everything but nothing will make these pesky css files appear in my image

Comment: Where are your CSS files? In the `app`? Do you get 404 (or other error) in the browser? Is your Django project in debug mode? Do you have Nginx or another proxy server running?

Comment: my css files are in  a static folder at the root of my project, I do indeed get a 404 error, it is not in debug mode and I dont have any proxy server running.

Comment: If it's not in debug mode, you need an Nginx (or other proxy) server to serve the static files.

Comment: `it is not in debug mode` Django is not supposed to serve static/media files in production, use nginx for that. `This method is grossly inefficient and probably insecure, so it is unsuitable for production.` [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/howto/static-files/#configuring-static-files)